# Please clarify convention for Django Media, Static, and Template file locations

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've started working on a project and decided I wanted to learn Django to do it. I finished their basic tutorial on the framework, but it's still unclear to me how template, static files, and media files ought to be organized. Django instructs to organize files like this:

```
---Project
   |---manage.py
   |---db.sqlite3
   |---site
   |   |---settings.py
   |   |---urls.py
   |   |---wsgi.py
   |---app1
       |---templates
       |   |---app1
       |       |---templatefiles...
       |---static
           |---app1
               |---exampleDirectory(photos)
                   |---photo.jpg
```

I understand why we create subdirectories of the same app name inside the static and template directories. This allows us to namespace our templates/static files, and refer to them specifically when/if our app is packaged and used on another site with templates/files of the same name. What I don't understand is two things:

1. What we do when we are building two applications on the same site that need access to the same templates, static, and media files?
2. Where should the media root folder usually be kept?

Should the project look something like this?

```
---Project
       |---manage.py
       |---db.sqlite3
       |---site
       |   |---settings.py
       |   |---urls.py
       |   |---wsgi.py
       |   |---templates
       |   |---media
       |   |---static
       |---app1
       |---app2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got shared assets, static/templates etc you could put them in the `site` app or at the project root.

```
---Project
       |---manage.py
       |---db.sqlite3
       |---site
       |   |---settings.py
       |   |---urls.py
       |   |---wsgi.py
       |---app1
       |---app2
       |---static
       |---templates
```

With regards to a `media` directory you don't need to worry about that locally and in app development. That directory is used by django for files uploaded via the site, `FileField` would upload to the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting. So you wouldn't create files in that path during development, all your files are static.

I think it makes more sense to put these at the project root so that a shared base template would live in `Project/templates/base.html` and you can just do `{% extends base.html %}` from your templates.

That keeps things simple & easy to follow. The other important reason to bundle app static/html into a folder of the app name is that when django does `collectstatic` the static folders of your apps all get bundled into your static root, usually a folder called `static-collection` or similar. By having the combined content split by app name, you avoid any conflict in the names of files, everything can have a `style.css` without getting mixed up etc.

Comment: Thanks, this does clarify the matter mostly. Thing is my project will have an app that takes user uploaded content via a model that uses a FileField. Then the second app will need to be able to access the uploaded content. To do this, would we create a folder in the project root folder as well?

Comment: @jkaros user uploaded content should be accessed using the database objects used to store those files. You don't need to worry about creating a folder for them in your development, you just define a setting as to where they'll live. Have a read of the docs here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/

Comment: @markwalker_ you said, "FileField would upload to the MEDIA_ROOT setting. So you wouldn't create files in that path during development, all your files are static.". In my case I am doing file upload then I want to store the uploaded file in development for testing purposes. Wouldn't I want to create files in the MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: If the files are important, maybe you could sync the data or just upload the same files in dev as you do in production, as a test, doing dev before production?